# Finite Projective Dimension implies non vanishing Ext

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Suppose the projective dimension of a module $M$ is $n < \infty$. Does there exist a free $R$-module $F$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M, F) \not = 0$?

Can't we write the free module as a direct sum of $R$'s and then we just need to show $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M, R) \not = 0$? So does this work actually for any free module?

Comment: If you show that $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,R)\neq0$, then because there exists an $F'$ such that $F\cong R\oplus F'$ we have that $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,F)\cong \operatorname{Ext}^n(M,R)\oplus \operatorname{Ext}^n(M,F')\neq0$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $F\cong R^{(I)}$ is a direct sum of $|I|$ copies of $R$ for some set $I$, then it is not true in general that $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,F)\cong\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,R)^{(I)}$, for $\operatorname{Ext}$ distributes only over *finite* direct sums in the second argument.

Comment: I've proved somewhere on this site the following result: Let $R$ be a noetherian ring and $M\neq 0$ a finitely generated $R$-module with $\mathrm{pd}_R(M)=n$. Then $\mathrm{Ext}_R^n(M,R)\neq 0$.

Comment: @YACP, since in that case one can take f.g. projective modules in the resolution of $M$ and Ext is additive in the second argument, one can deduce that from my answer too.

Comment: I couldn't  find your answer when I looked for it before —if you recover it, please do add a link here!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It wasn't easy to find it, but finally I've got it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210304/modules-with-projective-dimension-n-have-not-vanishing-mathrmextn

Comment: @YACP, searching is a pain way too often :-/

Answer (score 4):

If you ask the question

> if $M$ is an $R$-module of projective dimension $n$, is $\operatorname{Ext}^n(M,R)\neq0$?

then the answer is surpring: *it depends*. When $R=\mathbb Z$, this is essentially known as [Whitehead's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_problem) and Shelah proved that its answer depends on the specific set theory that you choose. Indeed, he showed that depending on the background set theory, there exist abelian groups $M$ which are not free (so that their projective dimension is $1$) such that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,\mathbb Z)=0$, or not.

$$\bullet\bullet\bullet$$

For the original question in which you look just for a free module:

Suppose the projective resolution of $M$ ends with $$\cdots\leftarrow P_{n-1}\xleftarrow{\hskip2ex d\hskip2ex }P_n\leftarrow 0$$ and suppose $P_n$ is a direct summand of the free module $F$. Applying the functor $\hom(\mathord-,F)$ we get a complex ending with $$\cdots\to\hom(P_{n-1},F)\xrightarrow{\hskip2ex d^*\hskip2ex }\hom(P_n,F)\to0$$ $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M,F)$ is the cokernel of the map $d$. To show it is not zero, it is enough to show that $d$ is not surjective.

Now let $i:P_n\to F$ be the inclusion and let $j:F\to P_n$ be a retraction of $i$, so that $ji=1_{P_n}$. The element $i\in\hom(P_n,F)$ is not in the image of $d$. Otherwise we'd have a map $r:P_{n-1}\to F$ such that $rd=i$, so composing with $j$ we'd have $jrd=ji=1_{P_n}$. It follows that $jr:P_{n-1}\to P_n$ is a retraction for the map $d$. This is impossible, because the projective dimension of $M$ is exactly $n$.

Comment: Interesting. So then trying to show $Ext^n(M, R)$ is not zero is probably the wrong way to go. I just want to show there is some free module $F$ where $Ext^n(M, F) \not = 0$.